# shred command overwrite value?

Tags: linux, shred

I'm trying to determine what `shred` uses to overwrite a file. Here's the [description](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_shred.htm):

> Overwrite the specified FILE(s) repeatedly, in order to make it harder
>   for even very expensive hardware probing to recover the data.

Can anyone confirm the overwirte occurs with random data (as opposed to 0's, which occurs with `--zero`)? The man page does not include the word 'random'.

If the command does not use random values, then what is used?

**Edit**: Here's the code I'm looking at. Its from OpenStack's [lvm.py](https://github.com/openstack/cinder/commit/bb06ebd0f6a75a6ba55a7c022de96a91e3750d20), and its used to wipe a volume upon deletion:

```
+  elif FLAGS.volume_clear == 'shred':
+      clear_cmd = ['shred', '-n3']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The MAN and INFO pages for coreutils `shred` do not explicitly state how random data is used within its overwrite process, however, it implies that random data is used for overwrite, in the description of `--zero`:

> ‘--zero’
>
> Normally, the last pass that shred writes is made up of random data.
>   If this would be conspicuous on your hard drive (for example, because
>   it looks like encrypted data), or you just think it's tidier, the
>   --zero option adds an additional overwrite pass with all zero bits. This is in addition to the number of passes specified by the
>   --iterations option.
>   http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shred.1.html

and the

> ‘--random-source=file’
>
> Use file as a source of random data used to overwrite and to choose pass ordering. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shred.1.html

implies that you can specify the device used to provide the random (/dev/urandom, etc). More info here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources

That the --zero specifically states that it is written with an additional pass, I believe they are insistent that a [guttman method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) be used for the initial overwrite.